# How can I see what files are being processed by tsc?

Tags: typescript

Is there any flag to tsc which makes it a bit more verbose about what it's doing? I found --terse and --verbose references, but not sure these are old flags or proposed ones, because none of them works.

I'd like to see which files it's processing, for example.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to see which files it's processing, for example.

There is no flag for that.

## More

You can find the user facing (developers trying to compile TS to JS) options with `tsc --help`

These and a bit more options are documented on the TypeScript website : https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

And *all* options in the [this file in the TypeScript source code](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/0eb0fb6d728a64d4b7dfffc06a4fd0946cf1ddd1/src/compiler/commandLineParser.ts).

Comment: There's also a [decent page on the TypeScript website listing a lot of the flags](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)...

Comment: Thanks. I've added to the answer 

Answer (score 1):

Use `npx tsc --build --verbose` per the [TypeScript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html):

```
$ npx tsc --build --verbose
[3:47:04 PM] Projects in this build:
    * tsconfig.json

[3:47:04 PM] Project 'tsconfig.json' is out of date because output file 'src/index.js' does not exist

[3:47:04 PM] Building project '/home/mike/Code/mycompany/mpackage/tsconfig.json'...
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest simple option, which I personally like using to avoid the 'no output at all' default, is:

```
tsc --listEmittedFiles
```

It doesn't show files while being processed unfortunately (I agree that would be nice!), but it does at least give an indication of what it has done, albeit at the last second of processing it seems.

You can also set this in tsconfig.json of course, under "compilerOpttions":

```
"listEmittedFiles": true,
```

Answer (score 0):

`--listFiles` lists all processed files, while `--listFilesOnly` does the same while skipping the actual compilation.